# display each record one below the other in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following table table with fields:
`name,surname,field,class`. The table have the following records:

```
  name        surname  field        class
 William       Smith    History      A1
 Mary          Adams    Maths        A2
 Stev          Goth     Literature   C2
 Helen         Maguire  Chemistry    A1
```

I want to display the aforemantioned elements with the following figure

```
History(A1) William Smith
Maths(A2) Mary Adams
Literature(C2) Stev Goth
Chemistry(A1) Helen Maguire
```

I try this in order to recover my data from db:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field SEPARATOR '<br>') AS field, 
GROUP_CONCAT(class SEPARATOR '<br>') AS field,
GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '<br>') AS field,
GROUP_CONCAT(surname SEPARATOR '<br>') AS field  
FROM teacher
```

And display my data into table like this

```
<td>".$row['field']." ( ".$row['class']." ) ".$row['name]." ".$row['surname']."</td></tr>";
```

But display each data in a new line. 
Also I try this:
`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(field,'(', class, ')',' ',name,' ',surname) SEPARATOR '<br>')` without result
Any idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: Why won't you concat the strings when displaying in PHP instead of concat in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `GROUP_CONCAT`. Just do a regular `SELECT`:

```
SELECT name, surname, field, class FROM teacher;
```

and then loop through your rows in PHP.

Comment: I use this firstly and font return my results in the form that i want. I want each record in new line in obe cell of table with my aforementioned figure

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use regular SELECT. I put td before while loop and close td after while loop. To
 display each record one under the other I use special character \n. The whole code:

```
$result=SELECT name, surname, field, class FROM teacher;
echo "<td>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['field']." ( ".$row['class'].") "  .$row['name']." ".$row['surname'].  "\n";
}
echo "</td>";
```